# get the access Token of my connected user **Passport** Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to get the token of my connected user .

That because I need to send it to a third party.
I used the

```
 $connectedUser = auth()->user()
```

to get the connected User.

How can I get the access token?

Comment: The token is stored on Users table?

Comment: Please update your question with brief explanation and take your time to re-frame it. if you're using passport token we're gonna need to know 1. how you stored it ? 2. how are you accessing it ? 3. what  is the exact problem ?

Comment: This sounds like an incredibly bad idea. You're essentially wanting to send a password to a third party that will allow them to log in as any of your users.